# JS countdown doesn't work on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, countdown

I have a problem implementing JS redirect countdown...
Here you can see button html, when I click on it it should start redirect countdown:

```
<footer>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Reset Password
    </button>
</footer>
```

And here is js:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    var count = 3;
    var countdown = setInterval(function(){
    $("#redirect").text(count);
        if (count == 0) {
            clearInterval(countdown);
            window.open('index.php', "_self");

        }
    count--;
    }, 1000);
});
```

The problem is that when I'm clicking on button it doesn't do anything not counting not redirecting.. If I move script out of button click event then it works properly.. What am I missing and doesn't understand here?

Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your button is a `submit` button, i.e. it will submit the current form and will definitely refresh the page, which will result in your script being terminated.

You should add `e.preventDefault()` if you want to avoid the default behavior of the submit button

```
$("button").click(function(e) {
    var count = 3;
    var $that = $(this);
    var countdown = setInterval(function(){
        $("#redirect").text(count);
        if (count == 0) {
            clearInterval(countdown);

            window.open('index.php', "_self");

            // submit now
            $that.closest('form').submit();
        }
        count--;
    }, 1000);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Ok this works thanks, but it stops my PHP scripts.. So what can I do if I still need this button to work as submit?

Comment: Do you want to submit after counting down?